# Cogstack NiFi on Windows 10 - Sample DB doesn't get populated

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-nifi

I am trying to get the Cogstack NiFi Docker implementation running on my Windows machine.
https://github.com/CogStack/CogStack-NiFi

When you run the Docker command;

```
docker-compose -f services.yml up -d samples-db
```

It is supposed to run this code from the services.yml (https://github.com/CogStack/CogStack-NiFi/blob/master/deploy/services.yml)

```
    services:

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Postgres container with sample data                                       #
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
  samples-db:
    image: postgres:11.4-alpine
    container_name: cogstack-samples-db
    restart: always
   
    volumes:
      # mapping postgres data dump and initialization
      - ../services/pgsamples/db_dump/db_samples-pdf-text-small.sql.gz:/data/db_samples.sql.gz:ro
      - ../services/pgsamples/init_db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_db.sh:ro
      # data persistence
      - samples-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
    # <host:container> expose the postgres DB to host for debugging purposes
      - 5555:5432
    #expose:
    #  - 5432
    networks:
      - cognet
```

And thus the init_db.sh (https://github.com/CogStack/CogStack-NiFi/blob/master/services/pgsamples/init_db.sh)

But unfortunately the data does not get populated.

When I try manually running init_db.sh it gives an error;

```
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # ./init_db.sh
Creating database: db_samples and user: test
psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

What could be the reason ?